# third party library`s webpack alias path cannot resolve in my package

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

It is hard to explain every situation in title..

Environment : React, Webpack, Typescript, Babel

I have two packages and i want to use my component library in My webpage

When I import and use it, my webpack-devserver can`t understand the symbol that I applied using webpack alias to the component library.

- debug-react : My React Component Library
- webpack-test : My React WebPage

[image]

I want to import the location of the debug-react directly and use it in the webpack-test.

I import `Counter` component from `debug-react` Component. and Counter component is made like this.

[image]

when i run using webpack-devserver in `webpack-test`, the following error appears.

[image]

I Know why that error appears. Because '@' is defined in `debug-react`s webpack alias
so my `webpack-test` can`t understand that symbol. However i want to solve this problem.
[image]

Is there a way to make `webpack-test` understand symbols from other libraries? I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know.

I Attached a link just in case. Thank you..!!

https://github.com/rbals0445/playground/blob/main/debug-react/src/components/Counter/Counter.tsx